# setcontext and makecontext to call a generic function pointer

Tags: c++, c, assembly, 32bit-64bit, ucontext

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518254/32bit-to-64bit-inline-assembly-porting/2518875) I had the problem to port the code:

```
unsigned long stack[] = { 1, 23, 33, 43 };

/* save all the registers and the stack pointer */
unsigned long esp;
asm __volatile__ ( "pusha" );
asm __volatile__ ( "mov %%esp, %0" :"=m" (esp));

for( i = 0; i < sizeof(stack); i++ ){
    unsigned long val = stack[i];
    asm __volatile__ ( "push %0" :: "m"(val) );
}

unsigned long ret = function_pointer();

/* restore registers and stack pointer */
asm __volatile__ ( "mov %0, %%esp" :: "m" (esp) );
asm __volatile__ ( "popa" );
```

To a 64bit platform and many guys told me I should use the *setcontext()* and *makecontext()* functions set instead due to the calling conversion differences between 32 and 64 bits and portability issues.

Well, I really can't find any useful documentation online, or at least not the kind I need to implement this, so, how can I use those functions to push arguments onto the stack, call a generic function pointer, obtain the return value and then restore the registers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i'm using libffi .

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page has a decent [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setcontext#Example).

This is not the solution you are looking for.  `makecontext` doesn't take an array but a variable argument list.  So, in order to call it you need a function to convert an array to an argument list.  Since that is what you want `makecontext` for, by the time you can use it you have already solved your problem.

I don't know what the solution is, but this is a dead end.

Comment: Ok, but HOW do i insert ulong values onto the stack?

Comment: Ok got it, but the problem is that makecontext wants the arguments of the functions and i do not know their number, they could be 2 arguments as none, or 4 ...